# Laravel total of products from Pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

```
 @foreach($order->products as $product)

                    <tr>

                        <td> {{ $product->id }}</td>
                        <td> {{ $product->name }}</td>
                        <td> {{ $product->getRelationValue('pivot')->qty }} </td>
                        <td> {{ $product->getRelationValue('pivot')->price }} </td>
                        <td> {{ $total = $product->getRelationValue('pivot')->price * $product->getRelationValue('pivot')->qty }} </td>
                    </tr>

                @endforeach
Grand Total:{{$total}}
```

I would like to show the total value. Can someone help me out?
And also the random access to $product->id in format 1,2,3....

Comment: You shouldn't have that logic in the view. Add methods to the Models and call they from the view

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#aggregates

Comment: You may probably want to add a comment to the answers below, so they can follow you through.

Comment: Can you add your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like below code:

```
@php
$grnadTotal = 0;
@endphp

 @foreach($order->products as $product)
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
       <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
       <td>{{ $product->getRelationValue('pivot')->qty }}</td>
       <td>{{ $product->getRelationValue('pivot')->price }}</td>
       <td>{{ $total = $product->getRelationValue('pivot')->price * $product->getRelationValue('pivot')->qty }}</td>
    </tr>

   @php
      $grnadTotal += $total;
   @endphp
@endforeach

Grand Total:{{$grnadTotal}}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

**Grand Total:** `{{$order->products->count()}}`